# Haskell calling functions within functions

Tags: haskell

I have a function called bounds1Accum. this function works great

```
bounds1Accum ::  [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
bounds1Accum l min max = (minimum (min:l), maximum (max:l))
```

What I am having problems with is I need another function called bounds1 which will take in just a list and return a min max pair. This function is supposed to wrap around bounds1accum and check to first see if the list being passed to it is empty or not. if the list is empty it will return Nothing or it will Just return the result of calling the bounds1Accum function.

I need two cases and for my signature I have

```
bounds1 :: [l] -> Maybe(min,max)
bounds1 [] = Nothing (which I am unsure if this will be correct)
```

then the 2nd case is where I am stumped
I originally had

```
bounds1 l  min max  = if null l then Nothing else Just $ bounds1 bounds1Accum min max
```

but this does not even compile so if anyone can offer suggestions or another way I can look at this problem it would be great. This is for an assignment so I do not want the answer but more so just guidance or help solving the problem.
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest writing it with guards, rather than if-then-else.  Mostly because that looks more like piece-wise function definition, which is what we're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you do not have `min` and `max` as arguments. You have to take those values from the list.

The `if` is unnecessary, since you already handle the empty list in the first case.

And why is there `bounds1` before the use of `bounds1Accum`?

Comment: so bounds1 [] = Nothing is okay for first case? and case to should be  bounds1 l = Just $ bounds1 bounds1Accum l min max? I put bounds1 first because it is supposed to wrap around bounds1Accum. Maybe I am thinking of it the wrong way.

Comment: I can add the actual needed specifications if that would be more helpful.

Comment: @benzo_nerd I think wrapping bounds1Accum just means calling it with the right arguments. And yes, first case is OK.

Comment: when I try to run this it tells me I have wrong number of arguments for case # 2 and my signature. my case #2 looks like this       bounds1 l  = Just $ bounds1 bounds1Accum l min max
I tried switching bounds1 and bounds1Accum too with same result

Comment: Again, I don't understand what is bounds1 doing just in front of bounds1Accum. BTW, are you sure bound1Accum is implemented as it should? It doesn't do what its name suggests.

Comment: bounds1Accum takes a list of numbers and a minimum and maximum and when called returns a min max pair. For example bounds1Accum[6,9,3] 5 10 will return (3,10).. It works I also tried writing it with a foldr solution but that one did not compile correctly so I went with what I currently have. As far as what bounds1 is doing just in front of bounds1Accum I must need to re read on some concepts because is how I thought it would work with the $ which acts as a parentheses if I remember correctly. I think what I am shooting for is f(g(x)) calling bounds1 with bounds1Accum as its parameter.

Comment: @benzo_nerd I'm sure bounds1Accum works, what I mean is: is it implemented the way it's supposed to be implemented? Isn't using minimum and maximum cheating? And you can't use bounds1Accum as a parameter unless you change the signature of bounds1. You just need to simply call bounds1Accum.